# Using python in Blender how to extrude and rotate?

Tags: python, blender, mesh

I need to extrude a mesh successively and rotate the mesh at every step.  This can be done in the user interface as shown below.

[image]

I have accomplished the successive extrusions but cannot make the rotations in python.  Please let me now what function rotates the selected mesh.

Answer (score 0):

```
            bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=deltaRot)
```

Where deltaRot is the change in rotation of the selected mesh.